# Searching for Lodging Along Interstates

Tags: usa, online-resources, driving, accommodation, road-trips

I would like to find accommodations along a stretch of interstate between Two Cities in Minnesota, USA
Is there a website, or other accessible (phone or text) service that would allow me to search accommodations by road instead of by town? Such that a hotel in MiddleOfNowhere is just as likely as a lodge in BigBustlingCity.

To Clarify, the two cities are *Very* far Apart.

Comment: Many tools offer to search within a radius you define, if you include the two cities in your circle, hotels along the road will be a subset of the results shown

Comment: @blackbird I have found that unless I break up the search into smaller searches, I get lots of places 100's of miles out of the way.

Answer (score 5):

Google Hotel Finder [used to allow you to draw a specific area on a map](http://lifehacker.com/5825686/google-hotel-finder-lets-you-draw-map-areas-and-filter-hotel-lists-to-find-the-perfect-place-to-stay) but that service has been shut down and integrated into Google Maps.

[Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/search/hotel/@46.1840754,-96.3018571,7z) may be your best bet, you can search for "hotel" then set your dates. You can drag through the map along the road you're looking at or you can zoom out and focus only on the results along the road you're looking at, you may need to click through several pages of results since google wont necessarily show them on the map if you're zoomed out really far.

[image: Google Maps hotel search screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

There are apps for this.

For example, Android has the free [iExit Interstate Exit Guide](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metrocket.iexitapp) app which, in real time, locates where you are and shows upcoming exits and amenities.

Additionally, if you're not averse to print (or as a back-up or planner), the most comprehensive guide is [Next Exit: The Most Complete Interstate Highway Guide Ever Printed (2016) by Mark Watson](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0984692142)

Answer (score 3):

The Waze and Map.me apps for smart phones access Open Street Map which you can also access in web browser.  It shows many things, including hotels.  Data is not complete of course.

Google maps and Apple maps also show such things, but are also not complete.  A smartphone app and website WalkScore.com shows things on a map or in a list ordered by distance.  **None** of them show everything, but in combination, you can get a lot of info.

I would use the map view, and zoom in on each intersection.  When a hotel icon appears. click on it to get information, which usually includes links to reviews and to the hotel's website.

Also, many hotel/hostel booking websites have a search on map option.  Often it takes a while to find and doesn't work well, but it might be worth a try.  Of course, those sites only list hotels that can afford to pay for being listed.

Comment: I just checked Trivago.  Apparently they changed their name to agoda, but their map option is easy to find.  Type in a city on the route and search.  Then click the map link.  Zoom in/out and pan the the map along your route.  If you don't like it updating constantly while you move, turn that off in the upper left corner.

Comment: FYI - [Waze](Waze.com) started with Open Street Maps and a few other free sources, but they've always used Google as their back up search. Now that they're owned by Google, they're fairly tightly coupled with the multi-colored search engine. And, just for kicks, many of Google Map's reports of traffic come directly from Waze. Again, just FYI...

Comment: Thanks.  I'm primarily pedal-powered, so I rarely use Waze.  Now I'll remove it from my iPad.  :-)